# function returns incorrect boolean value in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am using drool rule engine to process business rules. For below rule i am getting incorrect response.

```
rule "H13: Offer not valid for channelType requesting offers"
activation-group "OFFER"
salience 4
    when
      offer : OfferEligibilityRulesData(isOfferInvalidForRequestedChannelType(getOfferChannelType(),getRequestChannelType()))
    then
          offer.setInEligible("Offer channelType type is not equal to requesting channelType type","0028","H13");
end

function boolean isOfferInvalidForRequestedChannelType(String offerChannel, String requestChannel){
  return offerChannel!="ALL" && offerChannel!=requestChannel;
}
```

When i call this rule with offerChannelType="ALL" and requestchannelType="mobile" function returns incorrect result value TRUE. expected value is FALSE.

when remove the function call, and write its body in the rule itself then everything works fine.

```
rule "H13: Offer not valid for channelType requesting offers"
activation-group "OFFER"
salience 4
    when
      offer : OfferEligibilityRulesData(getOfferChannelType()!="ALL" && getOfferChannelType()!=getRequestChannelType())
    then
          offer.setInEligible("Offer channelType type is not equal to requesting channelType type","0028","H13");
end
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in first method? Also, unit test for first method are also working fine. Only when i run the application i get this issue

Comment: Why there is a Java tag ?

Comment: Because drools is a java library